# Using configuration of base web template in custom web template

Tags: 2010, feature, web-template

I'm creating a custom web template, and I'd like for my configuration only to add the things I need above and beyond what's in the base web template (in my case, CMSPUBLISHING#0).  My template works alright, but none of the configuration items from CMSPUBLISHING#0 are present in sites created from it.

Is this just the way templates work, or am I doing something wrong?  If the former, then what's the point of having a base template in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way they work.

You need to port over all the features referenced by the OOTB site definition that you use as a base (which I agree is dumb on some levels, although it does give you total control, so you don't have to inherit anything...)

You'll also need to port any modules that are provided in the OOTB site def into custom modules wrapped in features.

It took me 20mins to do the Enterprise Search Centre a few weeks ago.